# Export Flash Frame as PDF

Tags: flash, frame, pdf-conversion

I'm looking for a toolkit/command line/library that will let me export frames or a single frame of a .swf to a pdf. I'd rather not have to write my own converter.

I'm looking for a vector solution...not bitmap.

There is a [Swftools thread](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/swftools-common/2011-01/msg00051.html) on swf2pdf...but I can't seem to follow it. If it can be better explained, or if there's a compiled version of gfx2gfx, it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: Is it OK if it's just a bitmap rather than a vector?

Comment: I can do bitmap. I need vector to allow the text to be searchable/scalable.